# Inheriting from WPF UserControl defined in different assembly

Tags: wpf, user-controls, assemblies, inheritance

I realize there are some old threads that discuss this, but I don't believe they are still appropriate.

I have a WPF UserControl named TextControl.  This has an XAML and code behind component.

I want to derive from TextControl a class named LookupTextControl.  I had this working when LookupTextControl and TextControl where in the same assembly.  However, I have now broken TextControl into a seperate assembly (DLL) and it no longer works.  When I instaintiate a new instance of LookupTextControl and work through the constructor it is failing on the call to InitializeComponent in the TextControl class.

If I remove the XAML portion from TextControl it will work.

I realize that once upon a time you couldn't do this even in the same assembly.  It appears that support has been added within a single assembly but not between assemblies.

Can anyone shed light on why this doesn't work in my case and if there is an elegant way around it with keeping the XAML componenet?

Comment: Did you include all assemblies of the same version referenced by your xaml?

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting and if it is a XamlParseException, what is the InnerException?